# Component from Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5

I have just update my site from joomla 1.5 to joomla 2.5. And now I am getting error of compatibility issue. This is an error:

Strict Standards: Declaration of MyController::display() should be compatible with JController::display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false)

Please help me out...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error message, you need to change the MyController class's display function to accept two parameters.

You probably have this:

```
public function display() {
     ....
}
```

And it needs to accept two parameters like the base JController class:

```
public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false) {
     ....
}
```

Even if you never use them, standard functions likely will, so it is best to match the parameters of the functions that you override in your classes.

Comment: thanks david but i found the solution. Whatever you suggest that I have already done.In order to resolve this problem you just need to make one change in configuration.php file of your site.

Comment: You should just know that you didn't actually "solve" or fix the error; you just hid it. Mostly you just need to know that if you run into other issues with the site, you will likely want to switch this back to get the error message for those errors.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

You just need to make only one change in the configuration.php file of your site.

change this line from,

public $error_reporting = 'default';

To,

public $error_reporting = 'none';

& thats all.. This will not show the strict standards message.